# Append source code to flash image when programming an AVR

Tags: arduino, avr, atmega, linux, attiny

Is it possible for Arduino / ATmega / ATtiny when programming the device to attach the C source code at the end the machine code flash image? That way if I have the device, I can always retrieve the source code by reading flash memory.

Easiest way I can think of myself is some include-like statement at the end of the C-program that reads the source code from file and attaches it as data to the program. But I have no clue how to do that.

Comment: The source code for a microcontroller is usually useless without the schematic for the circuit it is in.

Comment: @TurboJ - I agree, I mention other documents in my answer. But if a program is well documented it includes in comment a complete listing of all I/O. And as I understand it OP wants to distribute the controller on its PCB.

Comment: Or you can have all of this on something like a subversion server hosted online... then your computer and the server have full logs and access.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should always be able to add *any* kind of data to your code. Just create a text array which you fill with the C code.

```
char source_code[9189] = {'m', 'a', 'i', 'n', '(', ')', 13, 10, '{' ,'}', 0};
```

You'll definitely want to write a program to create the array from a text file!

---

Personally I think this is a bad way to do it. Get organized! Include a code reference including version number, which refers to the code *on your PC*. You may even add the possibility to read out the reference in-system. I often include code that outputs the controller's identification over UART when a certain test pin is pulled low, like it would on a test block. The test block could then display it as for example

> Program ID: **10121**
>   Revision: **02**

This should be enough to find the source code back on your PC.

**edit**
If the idea is to let the code travel with the controller so that you can get it to other PCs, then I would also use Fake's idea: instead of just sending the program's idea you could purge the complete source that way.
Note that I'm still not completely convinced. Except for the most simple programs a program design is more than just the source code. What about flow charts or other design documents.

Comment: I like the pin pulling method! The thought behind my question is to solve the issue in case my PC is not available.

Comment: What are you going to with the C code if your PC is not available? And how are you going to read it??

Comment: @jippie You could store your code on an online cource code repository ([github](https://github.com/) or even Dropbox), if you want to have access to your code on PCs other than yours.

Comment: I don't want to depend on websites, disks or printouts. I have an AVR and I want to be able to pass it to someone else. If this someone feels like checking or improving the code, he/she can simply read it from the device.

Comment: A more relevant example is what if you give the IC to someone without an internet connection? Making the device capable of describing it's own code is a really cool idea. It's like the hardware equivalent of a [Quine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quine_(computing))

Comment: @jippie - You could combine stevenvh's idea of a test pin, and your idea of embedding the code in flash, and have it enumerate the code when you pull a test-pin low or high. That would have the advantage of making it easier to get the code-contents.

Comment: Agreed, but how do I attach the source code as data to the program?

Comment: @jippie - create an array of char and fill each element with a character from your source code. You'll want to write a program to convert the 10k source code to 10 000 char assignments. Added to my answer.

Comment: Don't forget to prevent your source-code includer from recursing. :)

Comment: @JRobert - Right, but if he wants to dump the table to UART in system he'll have to include a dummy table, otherwise he can't reference it.

Comment: Maybe my question is just as simple as 'How can I attach a datafile to my C-program, in such a way that the datafile is included in the final binary?'

Comment: 'You'll definitely want to write a program to create the array from a text file!' It already exists: `xxd -i`

Comment: @jippie As people are suggesting, the best way to do it is to generate a C source file as part of your build process. You really want to compress the source first, though, and even then it's going to eat up a big chunk of your memory - more than the compiled code.

Comment: I'll accept your answer as it brought me to figure out how to do it. I think it is unfair to accept my own question with you putting in so much effort.

Answer (score 2):

Found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/410980/include-a-text-file-in-a-c-program-as-a-char). It seems not to work for me because the file I'm trying to include has double and single quotes in it. 
It works if used with a makefile, but the Arduino IDE doesn't. It does work for programming from the command line though.

Combine the:

```
$ echo hello world | xxd -i > xxd.txt
```

xxd.txt contains:

```
  0x68, 0x65, 0x6c, 0x6c, 0x6f, 0x20, 0x77, 0x6f, 0x72, 0x6c, 0x64, 0x0a
```

or

```
$ cat blinker.ccp | xxd -i > xxd.txt
```

Then include it as follows:

```
const char text[] = {
#include "xxd.txt"
};
```

Just need to call it from the program somewhere in a print or so, otherwise the data will be optimized out.